# Slow Magento search

Tags: php, mysql, performance, magento

I'm running a Magento online shop (CE). When I first launched the shop a few weeks ago everything worked fine but now i recognize that the search has become incredibly slow. At the moment we have about 3000 products.

Loading the site takes just a second or so but searching takes about 14 seconds which is way too much! The search has been much faster a few weeks ago. Here are the things I already tried:

- I reseted the Cache and reindexed the store
- I tried to change from Combined search to LIKE and FULLTEXT Search
- I truncated the catalogsearch_* tables
- I tried to install several "search improvement"-
- I tried to optimize the mysql tables
- I tried to enable flat products
- I checked the server performance (CPU: ~ 0.3 - 11%, Mem: ~ 50%)

For me it's not obvious why the search speed is reducing. Has anyone further insights to the magento search module and has an idea why this happens and what I can do to increase the speed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your host?But search is slow is a broad issue,have you checked the slow queries?3000 products is nothing for mysql

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is to find a way to print the SQL statement(s) that Magento is using to perform your search  and run those queries directly on the DB. If the queries add up to the total load time, you know you can continue your optimization strictly on the DB side, which should be easier. If you get lucky and the queries are actually fast, you may have an issue somewhere else in the application. "Divide and conquer" :)

Comment: Where do I search for the SQL queries? I was unable to locate and print them so far.

Comment: Try using SOLR as search engine for Magento - there are some plugins for CE also - didn't try them though. As for the performance problem - turn on the query log (`file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`) as described here(http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/04/15/logging-database-queries-in-magento/) and then verify which queries are actually running so long. If the log will not show anything useful (ex. all the queries will be reletively short) then else thing you could do is run a Xdebug profiler and verify why the page is loading so long

Comment: I already installed SOLR - and in the logs the "longest" query was 0.2 Sec. So it has to be something in the code

Comment: so run the profiler and verify which functions are slow - you know how to do it and then read it?

Comment: Do you have a lot of installed third party extensions or did you install new extensions during last few weeks? Try to disable  extensions one by one, clear the cache and check search speed. I think you'll find some extension which so dramatically decrease searching.

Comment: I tried to use the Varian Profiler that is already installed within Magento and I found two possible "leaks" that both take 6 seconds. I already found the first one. Thank you guys.

Comment: The issue is the catalogsearch.leftnav Block renderer - but I couldn't find the performance issue - even if I delete the whole file it stays slow.

Comment: @DanielK. I am also facing the same issue, any solution found?
My catalog is huge, its around 100k products.